# Why is plymouthd crashing on startup?

Tags: boot, plymouth

Every time my laptop boots, I am greeted by several "Ubuntu 13.10 has experienced an internal error" dialogs once the graphical desktop environment (whatever it's called) is displayed. Apparently the problem originates from plymouthd, which is (unsurprisingly) the [daemon of the Plymouth boot splash application](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth#Daemon).

Has anyone ever found a fix for this type of issue?

(I would provide log excerpts but I'm not sure where to find them.)

Comment: How is this a duplicate???

Comment: I agree, this is not a duplicate...

Comment: I would expect a duplicate accusation would go accompanied with a link to the duplicate to avoid any discussion

Comment: There is nothing in the linked duplicate references `plymouthd` whatsoever. Vote to reopen.

Comment: The bug report is here but unassigned: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/1542000

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I have experienced the same error when I first installed Ubuntu 13.10 on the toshiba harman/kardon this week.

I solved the error with a single command:
Open a Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type:

```
sudo chown -R $USER: /lib/plymouth
```

Then all the permission issues are solved and the error is gone in the next boot.

Comment: Is 'user:user' supposed to my my user name? Or ...? As it stands the answer does not make sense to me. Thanks.

Comment: @ArtSwri user:user is actually user:group like mustafa:sudo, but in Ubuntu, when you create a user at setup or somewhere else, it usually creates a same group with your username and makes it your primary group. so if your user name is mustafa it should be mustafa:mustafa

Comment: This solution doesn't look very clean. What to do if the computer is multi-user?

Comment: Isn't hardman/kardon an audio company? LOL

Comment: Possible solution : sudo chmod 755 -R /lib/plymouth

Comment: It didn't actually worked for my multi-user system. I removed plymouth. To do that, open /etc/default/grub as root, and change line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quite splash", to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="verbose "

Comment: I used `chown -R <myusername>:<myusername> /lib/plymouth`. It worked for me.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried this a few months ago and it worked. Sorry I'm so late in accepting this as the answer.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea why this would work?  It hints the problem is due to access control.  But I've forbidden non-root user to execute `/sbin/plymouthd` by `chmod o-x /sbin/plymouthd`.  So only root can run it then there should be no problem access `/lib/plymouth`.

Comment: @TianrenLiu: You are right, it is weird. Could it be something like this: `/sbin/plymouthd` contains some invalid setting which cases the crash. If it is not owned by root then it is not used at all and default values are used, hence no crash.

Comment: This directory does not exist.

Comment: Doesn't work on Xubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Doesn't work neither on Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 ; folder doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm running 16.04, updated as of the date of this post and the problem recurred. Simply changing ownership on the /lib/plymouth tree, as suggested here did not solve the problem, I also needed to run `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/lib/plymouth`

Comment: On Ubuntu 17.04 Gnome I used `sudo chown -R : /sbin/plymouthd` without specifying user nor group and that worked.

Comment: @29axe From `man chown`: "If only a colon is given, ...  neither the owner nor the  group  is changed."

Answer (score 30):

```
sudo apt-get install plymouth-x11
```

That did help me with the issue.

Comment: This was tested on Ubuntu 16.10

Comment: Tested and apparently working on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Doesn't work on Xubuntu 15.04.

Comment: My case is very similar to @29axe's one, but I had to install only plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo to avoid the problem on XUbuntu 16.04.

Comment: Not working on Ubuntu Gnome 17.04

Comment: Tested in Xubuntu 16.04.3 and working.

Comment: This happened to me on upgrading from 18.04 to 18.10, installing plymouth-x11 fixed it.

Comment: Got https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/1802993 on Ubuntu 18.10. Wondering whether plymouth-x11 is going to fix it [EDIT] It seems it does... would rather like removing that dirty progress stuff tho

Comment: Crash happened after a lubuntu 18.04 upgrade.  This solved it, although at the first boot a different crash happened (openbox).

Answer (score 8):

A possible solution not mentioned here is to run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure Plymouth
```

From: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-gnome-default-settings/+bug/1536771

Comment: Worked for me on 16.04 / Gnome (`/lib/plymouth` doesn't exist so the accepted answer does not apply)

Comment: Worked for me on 18.10 / Gnome

Comment: 18.10 here, same problem on an upgrade, no /lib/plymouth nor /var/lib/plymouth - and this worked. Looks like a cleaner answer too.

Comment: worked for me for a while,trying again now ubuntu 18.10

Comment: working so far ubuntu 18.10

Comment: I can also confirm that this worked on Ubuntu 18.10. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing this problem, also. I found out that `/lib/plymouth` did not exist. **I installed `plymouth` using Synaptic** (but you can use whatever pkg installer you like), and it fixed the problem.

There are other plymouth packages, but it looked like they were already installed for Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 64 bit, which is what I am using. I also discovered that when I installed Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 32 bit, I didn't have this problem. For me, it was only a problem with the 64 bit install.

Answer (score 2):

In my case (Ubuntu Gnome 17.04), when I looked at the error details, it said the error was that /var/log/boot.log didn't exist. I just did 'sudo touch /var/log/boot.log' and the error went away.