# plymouthd crashes on startup - Intel HD 3000 - 15.10

Tags: intel-graphics, 15.10, plymouth

After upgrading to 15.10 from 15.04 I got a segfault in plymouthd on every startup.

This is what I can find in syslog:

```
Nov 11 12:22:26 H3A2764 systemd[1]: plymouth-start.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=11/SEGV
Nov 11 12:22:26 H3A2764 systemd[1]: plymouth-start.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 11 12:22:26 H3A2764 systemd[1]: plymouth-start.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
```

I uploaded `/var/crash/_sbin_plymouthd.0.crash` [here](http://latzinator.com/plymouthd.crash).

Comment: Can you provide the exact error message and possibly the stack trace please? You can retrieve it by booting recovery mode and looking in `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: I edited my question.  Please let me know if additional information is needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution for me was to tell plymouth to use framebuffer with these steps:

```
echo "FRAMEBUFFER=y" | sudo tee -a /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash && sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

Comment: This worked for me as well [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/407131/why-is-plymouthd-crashing-on-startup) other solution didn't.

Comment: Same for me. Other solution didn't work. This one does :) Thank you.

Comment: This seems to be working so far in 16.04.1 as well (Ubuntu Gnome3), on kernel 4.4.0-83-generic.