# Ubuntu 15.04 now 15.10 boots fine with Upstart fails to boot with SystemD

Tags: boot, upstart, systemd

I'm not sure how to solve this problem as both 15.04 and 15.10 with systemd get me only to an emergency shell whereas upstart works just fine. Having struggled with this for a whole version, help would be appreciated.

Here the last few lines of my dmesg:

```
[  100.633980] systemd[1]: Accepted new private connection.
[  100.634001] systemd-cgroups-agent[792]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/agent interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Agent member=Released cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.634005] systemd[1]: Got disconnect on private connection.
[  100.634180] systemd[1]: Got message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/agent interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Agent member=Released cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.634269] systemd[1]: Got disconnect on private connection.
[  100.636283] systemd[1]: Received SIGCHLD from PID 751 (resolvconf).
[  100.636293] systemd[1]: Child 751 (resolvconf) died (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
[  100.636307] systemd[1]: resolvconf.service: Child 751 belongs to resolvconf.service
[  100.636312] systemd[1]: resolvconf.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS
[  100.636382] systemd[1]: resolvconf.service: Changed running -> exited
[  100.636386] systemd[1]: resolvconf.service: cgroup is empty
[  100.637035] systemd[1]: Accepted new private connection.
[  100.637071] systemd-cgroups-agent[808]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/agent interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Agent member=Released cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.637077] systemd[1]: Got message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/agent interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Agent member=Released cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.637156] systemd[1]: Got disconnect on private connection.
[  100.643279] audit: type=1400 audit(1452853904.083:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=822 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  100.643283] audit: type=1400 audit(1452853904.083:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="chromium" pid=822 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  100.644807] audit: type=1400 audit(1452853904.083:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=822 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  100.644811] audit: type=1400 audit(1452853904.083:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=822 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  100.644814] audit: type=1400 audit(1452853904.083:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=822 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  100.644817] audit: type=1400 audit(1452853904.083:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=822 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  100.651499] audit: type=1400 audit(1452853904.091:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince" pid=822 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  100.651503] audit: type=1400 audit(1452853904.091:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="sanitized_helper" pid=822 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  100.651506] audit: type=1400 audit(1452853904.091:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince-previewer" pid=822 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  100.651508] audit: type=1400 audit(1452853904.091:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="sanitized_helper" pid=822 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  100.651700] systemd-journald[471]: Failed to forward syslog message: Connection refused
[  100.658209] systemd-journald[471]: Failed to forward syslog message: Connection refused
[  100.660713] systemd-journald[471]: Failed to forward syslog message: Connection refused
[  100.660786] systemd[1]: Received SIGCHLD from PID 737 (apparmor).
[  100.660797] systemd[1]: Child 737 (apparmor) died (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
[  100.660814] systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Child 737 belongs to apparmor.service
[  100.660821] systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=0
[  100.660836] systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Got final SIGCHLD for state start.
[  100.660951] systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Changed start -> exited
[  100.660955] systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Job apparmor.service/start finished, result=done
[  100.660960] systemd[1]: Started LSB: AppArmor initialization.
[  100.661034] systemd[1]: apparmor.service: cgroup is empty
[  100.661228] systemd[1]: networking.service: About to execute: /etc/init.d/networking start
[  100.661324] systemd[1]: networking.service: Forked /etc/init.d/networking as 828
[  100.661366] systemd[1]: networking.service: Changed dead -> start
[  100.661372] systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Raise network interfaces....
[  100.661701] systemd[828]: networking.service: Executing: /etc/init.d/networking start
[  100.662192] systemd[1]: Accepted new private connection.
[  100.662252] systemd-cgroups-agent[827]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/agent interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Agent member=Released cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.662323] systemd[1]: Got message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/agent interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Agent member=Released cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.662360] systemd[1]: apparmor.service: cgroup is empty
[  100.662382] systemd[1]: Got disconnect on private connection.
[  100.665820] systemd-journald[471]: Failed to forward syslog message: Connection refused
[  100.691237] systemd-journald[471]: Failed to forward syslog message: Connection refused
[  100.691276] systemd[1]: Received SIGCHLD from PID 828 (networking).
[  100.691288] systemd[1]: Child 828 (networking) died (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
[  100.691305] systemd[1]: networking.service: Child 828 belongs to networking.service
[  100.691309] systemd[1]: networking.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=0
[  100.691322] systemd[1]: networking.service: Got final SIGCHLD for state start.
[  100.691338] systemd[1]: networking.service: Changed start -> running
[  100.691342] systemd[1]: networking.service: Job networking.service/start finished, result=done
[  100.691349] systemd[1]: Started LSB: Raise network interfaces..
[  100.691528] systemd[1]: network.target changed dead -> active
[  100.691531] systemd[1]: network.target: Job network.target/start finished, result=done
[  100.691535] systemd[1]: Reached target Network.
[  100.691548] systemd[1]: network-online.target changed dead -> active
[  100.691550] systemd[1]: network-online.target: Job network-online.target/start finished, result=done
[  100.691553] systemd[1]: Reached target Network is Online.
[  100.691573] systemd[1]: Assertion 'r >= 0' failed at ../src/libsystemd/sd-event/sd-event.c:484, function source_io_unregister(). Ignoring.
[  100.691580] systemd[1]: Startup finished in 10.490s (kernel) + 1min 30.231s (userspace) = 4min 57.942s.
[  100.694597] systemctl[922]: Showing one /org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/ntp_2eservice
[  100.695050] systemd[1]: Accepted new private connection.
[  100.695102] systemctl[922]: Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.systemd1 object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/ntp_2eservice interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=GetAll cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.695144] systemd[1]: Got message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.systemd1 object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/ntp_2eservice interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=GetAll cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.695182] systemd[1]: ntp.service: Failed to load configuration: No such file or directory
[  100.695350] systemd[1]: Sent message type=method_return sender=n/a destination=n/a object=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=1 reply_cookie=1 error=n/a
[  100.695363] systemd[1]: ntp.service: Collecting.
[  100.695370] systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=UnitNew cookie=2 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.695374] systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=UnitRemoved cookie=3 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.695379] systemctl[922]: Got message type=method_return sender=n/a destination=n/a object=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=1 reply_cookie=1 error=n/a
[  100.695557] systemd[1]: Got disconnect on private connection.
[  100.696711] systemd[740]: emergency.service: Executing: /bin/plymouth --wait quit
[  100.696807] systemd[1]: Accepted new private connection.
[  100.696854] systemctl[923]: Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.systemd1 object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=Get cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.696894] systemd[1]: Got message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.systemd1 object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=Get cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.696906] systemd[1]: Sent message type=method_return sender=n/a destination=n/a object=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=1 reply_cookie=1 error=n/a
[  100.696942] systemctl[923]: Got message type=method_return sender=n/a destination=n/a object=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=1 reply_cookie=1 error=n/a
[  100.696982] systemd[1]: Got disconnect on private connection.
[  100.697687] systemctl[924]: Calling manager for StopUnit on ntp.service, ignore-dependencies
[  100.698157] systemd[1]: Accepted new private connection.
[  100.698217] systemctl[924]: Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.systemd1 object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=StopUnit cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.698268] systemd[1]: Got message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.systemd1 object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=StopUnit cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.698290] systemd[1]: ntp.service: Failed to load configuration: No such file or directory
[  100.698302] systemd[1]: Sent message type=error sender=n/a destination=n/a object=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=1 reply_cookie=1 error=Unit ntp.service not loaded.
[  100.698305] systemd[1]: Failed to process message [type=method_call sender=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=StopUnit signature=ss]: Unit ntp.service not loaded.
[  100.698307] systemd[1]: ntp.service: Collecting.
[  100.698313] systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=UnitNew cookie=2 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.698317] systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=UnitRemoved cookie=3 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.698318] systemctl[924]: Got message type=error sender=n/a destination=n/a object=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=1 reply_cookie=1 error=Unit ntp.service not loaded.
[  100.698322] systemctl[924]: Failed to stop ntp.service: Unit ntp.service not loaded.
[  100.698348] systemctl[924]: Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.systemd1 object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/ntp_2eservice interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=Get cookie=2 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.698371] systemd[1]: Got message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.systemd1 object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/ntp_2eservice interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=Get cookie=2 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.698392] systemd[1]: ntp.service: Failed to load configuration: No such file or directory
[  100.698404] systemd[1]: Sent message type=method_return sender=n/a destination=n/a object=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=4 reply_cookie=2 error=n/a
[  100.698407] systemd[1]: ntp.service: Collecting.
[  100.698413] systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=UnitNew cookie=5 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.698417] systemctl[924]: Got message type=method_return sender=n/a destination=n/a object=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=4 reply_cookie=2 error=n/a
[  100.698418] systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=UnitRemoved cookie=6 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.698427] systemctl[924]: Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.systemd1 object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/ntp_2eservice interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=Get cookie=3 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.698432] systemd[1]: Got message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.systemd1 object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/ntp_2eservice interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=Get cookie=3 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.698446] systemd[1]: ntp.service: Failed to load configuration: No such file or directory
[  100.698454] systemd[1]: Sent message type=method_return sender=n/a destination=n/a object=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=7 reply_cookie=3 error=n/a
[  100.698457] systemd[1]: ntp.service: Collecting.
[  100.698461] systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=UnitNew cookie=8 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.698466] systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=UnitRemoved cookie=9 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.698468] systemctl[924]: Got message type=method_return sender=n/a destination=n/a object=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=7 reply_cookie=3 error=n/a
[  100.698518] systemd[1]: Got disconnect on private connection.
[  100.699756] systemd-journald[471]: Failed to forward syslog message: Connection refused
[  100.705302] systemctl[945]: Showing one /org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/ntp_2eservice
[  100.705807] systemd[1]: Accepted new private connection.
[  100.705865] systemctl[945]: Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.systemd1 object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/ntp_2eservice interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=GetAll cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.705891] systemd[1]: Got message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.systemd1 object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/ntp_2eservice interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=GetAll cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.705917] systemd[1]: ntp.service: Failed to load configuration: No such file or directory
[  100.706081] systemd[1]: Sent message type=method_return sender=n/a destination=n/a object=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=1 reply_cookie=1 error=n/a
[  100.706085] systemd[1]: ntp.service: Collecting.
[  100.706091] systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=UnitNew cookie=2 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.706096] systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=UnitRemoved cookie=3 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.706097] systemctl[945]: Got message type=method_return sender=n/a destination=n/a object=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=1 reply_cookie=1 error=n/a
[  100.706272] systemd[1]: Got disconnect on private connection.
[  100.707508] systemd[1]: Accepted new private connection.
[  100.707532] systemctl[946]: Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.systemd1 object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=Get cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.707543] systemd[1]: Got message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.systemd1 object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=Get cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.707555] systemd[1]: Sent message type=method_return sender=n/a destination=n/a object=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=1 reply_cookie=1 error=n/a
[  100.707565] systemctl[946]: Got message type=method_return sender=n/a destination=n/a object=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=1 reply_cookie=1 error=n/a
[  100.707597] systemd[1]: Got disconnect on private connection.
[  100.708251] systemctl[947]: Looking for unit files in (higher priority first):
[  100.708253] systemctl[947]:  /etc/systemd/system
[  100.708254] systemctl[947]:  /run/systemd/system
[  100.708255] systemctl[947]:  /usr/local/lib/systemd/system
[  100.708256] systemctl[947]:  /lib/systemd/system
[  100.708257] systemctl[947]:  /usr/lib/systemd/system
[  100.708261] systemctl[947]: Looking for SysV init scripts in:
[  100.708262] systemctl[947]:  /etc/init.d
[  100.708263] systemctl[947]: Looking for SysV rcN.d links in:
[  100.708264] systemctl[947]:  /etc
[  100.708679] systemd[1]: Accepted new private connection.
[  100.708708] systemctl[947]: Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.systemd1 object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=GetUnitFileState cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.708716] systemd[1]: Got message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.systemd1 object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=GetUnitFileState cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.708734] systemd[1]: Looking for unit files in (higher priority first):
[  100.708736] systemd[1]:  /etc/systemd/system
[  100.708737] systemd[1]:  /run/systemd/system
[  100.708737] systemd[1]:  /usr/local/lib/systemd/system
[  100.708738] systemd[1]:  /lib/systemd/system
[  100.708739] systemd[1]:  /usr/lib/systemd/system
[  100.708742] systemd[1]: Looking for SysV init scripts in:
[  100.708743] systemd[1]:  /etc/init.d
[  100.708745] systemd[1]: Looking for SysV rcN.d links in:
[  100.708745] systemd[1]:  /etc
[  100.708758] systemd[1]: Sent message type=error sender=n/a destination=n/a object=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=1 reply_cookie=1 error=No such file or directory
[  100.708761] systemd[1]: Failed to process message [type=method_call sender=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=GetUnitFileState signature=s]: No such file or directory
[  100.708775] systemctl[947]: Got message type=error sender=n/a destination=n/a object=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=1 reply_cookie=1 error=No such file or directory
[  100.708780] systemctl[947]: Failed to get unit file state for ntp.service: No such file or directory
[  100.708798] systemd[1]: Got disconnect on private connection.
[  100.709062] systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+21 from PID 256 (plymouthd).
[  100.709064] systemd[1]: Disabling showing of status.
[  100.709281] systemd[1]: Received SIGCHLD from PID 894 (lockfile-touch).
[  100.709292] systemd[1]: Child 890 (lockfile-remove) died (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
[  100.709309] systemd[1]: networking.service: Child 890 belongs to networking.service
[  100.709356] systemd[1]: Child 894 (lockfile-touch) died (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
[  100.709368] systemd[1]: networking.service: Child 894 belongs to networking.service
[  100.709381] systemd[1]: networking.service: cgroup is empty
[  100.709434] systemd[1]: networking.service: Changed running -> exited
[  100.710095] systemd[1]: Accepted new private connection.
[  100.710157] systemd-cgroups-agent[948]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/agent interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Agent member=Released cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.710171] systemd[1]: Got message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/agent interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Agent member=Released cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.710261] systemd[1]: Got disconnect on private connection.
[  100.733791] systemd[1]: Received SIGCHLD from PID 740 (plymouth).
[  100.733811] systemd[1]: Child 740 (plymouth) died (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
[  100.733838] systemd[1]: emergency.service: Child 740 belongs to emergency.service
[  100.733843] systemd[1]: emergency.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=0
[  100.733924] systemd[1]: emergency.service: Running next control command for state start-pre.
[  100.733965] systemd[1]: emergency.service: About to execute: /bin/echo -e 'Welcome to emergency mode! After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view\nsystem logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or ^D to\ntry again to boot into default mode.'
[  100.734057] systemd[1]: emergency.service: Forked /bin/echo as 950
[  100.734440] systemd[950]: emergency.service: Executing: /bin/echo -e 'Welcome to emergency mode! After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view\nsystem logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or ^D to\ntry again to boot into default mode.'
[  100.734848] systemd[1]: Accepted new private connection.
[  100.734893] systemd[1]: Received SIGCHLD from PID 950 (echo).
[  100.734901] systemd[1]: Child 950 (echo) died (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
[  100.734913] systemd[1]: emergency.service: Child 950 belongs to emergency.service
[  100.734915] systemd[1]: emergency.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=0
[  100.734934] systemd[1]: emergency.service: Got final SIGCHLD for state start-pre.
[  100.734952] systemd[1]: emergency.service: About to execute: /bin/sh -c '/sbin/sulogin; /bin/systemctl --job-mode=fail --no-block default'
[  100.735012] systemd[1]: emergency.service: Forked /bin/sh as 952
[  100.735065] systemd[1]: emergency.service: Changed start-pre -> running
[  100.735182] systemd-cgroups-agent[949]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/agent interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Agent member=Released cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.735307] systemd[952]: emergency.service: Executing: /bin/sh -c '/sbin/sulogin; /bin/systemctl --job-mode=fail --no-block default'
[  100.735694] systemd[1]: Accepted new private connection.
[  100.735734] systemd[1]: Got disconnect on private connection.
[  100.735734] systemd-cgroups-agent[951]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/agent interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Agent member=Released cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.735933] systemd[1]: Got message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/agent interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Agent member=Released cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.735973] systemd[1]: Received SIGCHLD from PID 256 (plymouthd).
[  100.735990] systemd[1]: Child 256 (plymouthd) died (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
[  100.736018] systemd[1]: Got disconnect on private connection.
[  100.736998] systemd[1]: Accepted new private connection.
[  100.737018] systemd-cgroups-agent[954]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/agent interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Agent member=Released cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.737027] systemd[1]: Got message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1/agent interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Agent member=Released cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
[  100.737079] systemd[1]: Got disconnect on private connection.
[  103.609741] systemd[1]: systemd-udevd.service: Got notification message from PID 487 (WATCHDOG=1)
```

Comment: Is plymouth crashing? What does `systemctl --failed` say?

Comment: I'll check on Monday. But let's say this is the issue how would I circumvent it?

Comment: I'd guess it would be a systemd configuration issue. Was this a system that was upgraded from an earlier version of Ubuntu? If so, the quickest way to fix it may be to just install a fresh version of 15.10. Otherwise you'd need to figure out exactly how your config differs from a working install.

Comment: It was a fresh install for 15.04 but systemd never worked on this machine, I always had to fall back to upstart from day 1.

Comment: systemctl --failed lists 0 failed entries

Comment: Two ideas. 1. `Failed to get unit file state for ntp.service: No such file or directory` - try removing or disabling ntp. 2. Plymouth might be crashing (like [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/695761/plymouthd-crashes-on-startup-intel-hd-3000-15-10)). Check `dmesg` and `/var/log/syslog` for any crashes or errors.

Comment: No luck with that. So syslog doesn't actually show any new entries for a failed systemd boot. I must say I don't find the systemd output very informative. It is logs a lot of of fails and error messages some of which may just be part of normal operations. If 16.04 dumps upstart I guess I'm out of options and may have to switch distro.

Comment: systemd errors should be logged to syslog. Maybe something to do with `systemd-journald[471]: Failed to forward syslog message: Connection refused`. Could be [Debian bug #762700](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=762700) or some configuration problem with syslog or something else. You could try to fix it, but it might be easier to test a fresh install of 16.04 to see if it's already fixed.

Comment: True although as mentioned the 15.04 was a fresh install
thanks for your efforts in any case

Comment: If syslog isn't working you can check the errors using `journalctl`. Try `journalctl -xb`, `journalctl -b -p3` or `-p4`, or `journalctl -kp4` to just see the kernel log

Comment: did the journalctl -xb this morning, may have something to do with this:

1373:Jan 22 09:18:19 lc-m systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /mnt/SeqData1.
    1374:-- Subject: Unit mnt-SeqData1.mount has failed
    1378:-- Unit mnt-SeqData1.mount has failed.
    1381:Jan 22 09:18:19 lc-m systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
    1382:-- Subject: Unit local-fs.target has failed
    1386:-- Unit local-fs.target has failed.
 
or:    
    1389:Jan 22 09:18:19 lc-m systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Clean up any mess left by 0dns-up.
    1390:-- Subject: Unit dns-clean.service has failed

Answer (score 2):

OK this is silly but I found the solution the error had to do with an /etc/fstab entry for an USB drive:

/dev/disk/by-label/SeqData1 /mnt/SeqData1 nosuid,nodev,nobootwait,nofail,noauto,x-gvfs-show 0 0

I had to comment this one out and systemd booted fine.
Why this entry for a USB drive was there in the first place I'm not sure.
I tried first using nofail and nopootwait but that didn't help.
Still confused about all this but the problem is solved.