# Plymouthd crashes on startup in Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: plymouth

Plymouthd crashes on startup with the following error message.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is plymouthd crashing on startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/407131/why-is-plymouthd-crashing-on-startup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did a0b1's answer, edit /etc/default/grub, then restore:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Then, in the same file, find:

```
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

and change it to:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

Save the file, and then:

```
sudo update-grub
reboot
```

Comment: As stated above the removal of "quiet splash" did not fix the problem. I was reluctant to add the "..GFXMODE" line as I was not sure of its purpose.

Comment: @TerryDixon It limits the GRUB/splash screen to 640x480. Harmless, except that's what fixed my Plymouth crashes.

Comment: Thank you GFXMODE appears to have fixed the problem.

Comment: I assume I've accepted your answer.

Comment: @TerryDixon to accsept,log in and click on the area under the up/down vote buttons you will get some points too.

Comment: Did that do the right thing?

Answer (score 0):

It do look like advanced options-recovery mode and update grub fixes this error too,So it might be several ways to fix this.

I have not used terminal to update grub but this will most likely work too.

Sorry for the short answer.